# How to restore snapshot to Windows VM persistent boot disk

Tags: google-compute-engine

I created a Windows VM with a single 50GB persistent disk. I took a snapshot of the disk, and now wanted to see how I could use that snapshot to revert the boot disk back to a previous state, but it doesnt seem to be straightforward.

I shut down the VM, and using gcloud tried to detatch the current disk, but it says "Hot-remove of the root disk is not supported".

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

[Create a disk](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/disks/create) from your snapshot:

```
gcloud compute disks create --source-snapshot SNAPSHOT --zone ZONE
```

[Create an instance](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create) using the disk:

```
gcloud compute instances create INSTANCE --disk name=DISK_NAME boot=yes --zone ZONE
```

Verify it and remove the old instance if you don't need it. All these steps can be done through the Developers Console as well.